# my program fail to run

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have a little program in C and, despite there is no warnings from the compiler (netbeans with cygwin), it just fail to run without giving me any hint in the console. Is my compiler not working as it is supposed to? What could be wrong in the code?

Here is the code. The program basically create and sort some arrays many times to compare the different methods of sorting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/*
 *
 */
//void preenchendo (int, int);
//void bubblesort (int, int, int *, int *);
//void selectsort (int, int, int *, int *);
//void insertsort (int, int, int *, int *);

void preenchendo (int n, int vetor[n]) {

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int contador;

    for(contador = 0; contador < n; contador++) {
        vetor[contador] = rand() % n;
    }
}

void bubblesort (int vetor[], int n, int * troca, int * comp) {

    *troca = 0;
    *comp = 0;

    int foi = 0;
    int end = n;
    int contador;

    do{
        for(contador = 0; contador < end; contador++) {
            if(vetor[contador] > vetor[contador+1]){
                int aux = vetor[contador];
                vetor[contador] = vetor[contador+1];
                vetor[contador+1] = aux;
                foi=1;
                *troca++;
            }
            *comp++;
        }
        end--;
    }while(troca == 0);
}

void selectsort (int vetor[], int n, int * troca, int * comp) {

    *troca = 0;
    *comp = 0;
    int min;
    int contador, contador2;

    for(contador = 0; contador < n-1; contador++) {
        min = contador;
        for(contador2 = contador+1; contador2 < n; contador2++) {
            if(vetor[contador2] < vetor[min]) {
                min = contador2;
            }
            *comp++;
        }
        if(min != contador) {
            int aux = vetor[contador];
            vetor[contador] = vetor[min];
            vetor[min] = aux;
            *troca++;
        }
        *comp++;
    }
}

void insertsort (int vetor[], int n, int * troca, int * comp) {

    *troca = 0;
    *comp = 0;
    int aux;
    int contador;

    for(contador = 1; contador < n; contador++) {
        int element = vetor[contador];
        int pos = contador-1;

        while(pos >= 0 && element < vetor[pos]) {
            vetor[pos+1] = vetor[pos];
            pos--;
            *comp++;
            *troca++;
        }
        vetor[pos+1] = element;
    }
}

void main(int argc, char** argv) {
{
    int vetor1[1000], vetor2[10000], vetor3[50000], vetor4[500000]; //vetores originais
    int vet1[1000], vet2[10000], vet3[50000], vet4[500000]; //ordenados
    int veti1[1000], veti2[10000], veti3[50000], veti4[500000]; //ordenados inversamente
    int troca, comp, contador, contador2;

    preenchendo(1000, vetor1);
    preenchendo(10000, vetor2);
    preenchendo(50000, vetor3);
    preenchendo(500000, vetor4);
    for(contador = 0; contador < 1000; contador++) {
        vet1[contador] = vetor1[contador];
    }
    for(contador = 0; contador < 10000; contador++) {
        vet2[contador] = vetor2[contador];
    }
    for(contador = 0; contador < 50000; contador++) {
        vet3[contador] = vetor3[contador];
    }
    for(contador = 0; contador < 500000; contador++) {
        vet4[contador] = vetor4[contador];
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    clock_t inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    bubblesort(vet1, 1000, &troca, &comp);
    clock_t fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Bubble 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    bubblesort(vet2, 10000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Bubble 10000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    bubblesort(vet3, 50000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Bubble 50000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    bubblesort(vet4, 500000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Bubble 500000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    selectsort(vet1, 1000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Select 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    selectsort(vet2, 10000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Select 10000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    selectsort(vet3, 50000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Select 50000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    selectsort(vet4, 500000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Select 500000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    insertsort(vet1, 1000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Insert 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    insertsort(vet2, 10000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Insert 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    insertsort(vet3, 50000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Insert 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    insertsort(vet4, 500000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Insert 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    bubblesort(vet1, 1000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Bubble ordenado 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    bubblesort(vet2, 10000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Bubble ordenado 10000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    bubblesort(vet3, 50000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Bubble ordenado 50000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    bubblesort(vet4, 500000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Bubble ordenado 500000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    selectsort(vet1, 1000, &troca, &comp);
    printf("Select ordenado 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    selectsort(vet2, 10000, &troca, &comp);
    printf("Select ordenado 10000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    selectsort(vet3, 50000, &troca, &comp);
    printf("Select ordenado 50000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    selectsort(vet4, 500000, &troca, &comp);
    printf("Select ordenado 500000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    insertsort(vet1, 1000, &troca, &comp);
    printf("Insert ordenado 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    insertsort(vet2, 10000, &troca, &comp);
    printf("Insert ordenado 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    insertsort(vet3, 50000, &troca, &comp);
    printf("Insert ordenado 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    insertsort(vet4, 500000, &troca, &comp);
    printf("Insert ordenado 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    contador2 = 999;
    for(contador = 0; contador < 1000; contador++) {
        veti1[contador] = vet1[contador2];
        contador2--;
    }
    contador2 = 9999;
    for(contador = 0; contador < 10000; contador++) {
        veti2[contador] = vet2[contador2];
        contador2--;
    }
    contador2 = 49999;
    for(contador = 0; contador < 50000; contador++) {
        veti3[contador] = vet3[contador2];
        contador2--;
    }
    contador2 = 499999;
    for(contador = 0; contador < 500000; contador++) {
        veti4[contador] = vet4[contador2];
        contador2--;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    bubblesort(veti1, 1000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Bubble ordenado inv 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    bubblesort(veti2, 10000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Bubble ordenado inv 10000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    bubblesort(veti3, 50000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Bubble ordenado inv 50000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    bubblesort(veti4, 500000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Bubble ordenado inv 500000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    selectsort(veti1, 1000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Select ordenado inv 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    selectsort(veti2, 10000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Select ordenado inv 10000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    selectsort(veti3, 50000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Select ordenado inv 50000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    selectsort(veti4, 500000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Select ordenado inv 500000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    insertsort(veti1, 1000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Insert ordenado inv 1000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    insertsort(veti2, 10000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Insert ordenado inv 10000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    insertsort(veti3, 50000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Insert ordenado inv 50000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    inicio = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    insertsort(veti4, 500000, &troca, &comp);
    fim = clock()/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    printf("Insert ordenado inv 500000\n");
    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", (fim-inicio));
    printf("Trocas: %d\n", troca);
    printf("Comparacoes: %d\n\n", comp);

    system("pause");
    //return (0);
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the program fails to run? It just does not print anything? Can you run it in debug mode with Netbeans?

Comment: Aaaaand the debugger said what?

Comment: That is not a little program. At least not in the context of "something's wrong here, what can it be?".

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be stack overflow. Yes, really.

Assuming a 32-bit integer, these:

```
int vetor1[1000], vetor2[10000], vetor3[50000], vetor4[500000]; //vetores originais
int vet1[1000], vet2[10000], vet3[50000], vet4[500000]; //ordenados
int veti1[1000], veti2[10000], veti3[50000], veti4[500000]; //ordenados inversamente
```

end up using about 6732000 bytes, or around 6.4 MB. That can be more than the operating system thinks you should be using.

Consider trying to allocate those on the heap instead using `malloc()`, or checking what limits apply on your platform.

Comment: Wow! That's all I can say...

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey Okay ... so what do you mean? Did I make some mistake?

Comment: No.  Just shocked at the size of the arrays.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Surely, the process gets stopped and some error message raised?  Don't tell me that it exits with return code 0?